# SetUnlockedDeviceRequired() Android Key Hardening flag issue in Android 13 version when device is unlocked using Face recognition

Tags: android-keystore

As part of the security feature I am enabling **SetUnlockedDeviceRequired **android key store flag in my c# Xamarin code to insure that Keystore in not accessible if the device is locked and this works fine when user tried to login mobile device either using pin,password,pattern or fingerprint. The problem what I am facing is when I unlocked the **Android 13** mobile using Face recognition and launch the app it gets stuck at splash screen however the same worked for Android 11.Can any one has any input on why Face unlock does not work with SetUnlockedDeviceRequired key store flag with Android 13.

Any help will be greatly apricated.

Thanks!

SetUnlockedDeviceRequired should also work with Face biometric in Android device ( tested in version 13) but apparently it did not work. Looking for a solution.